# How to make this snippet DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know it's not that bad, but I can't help but wonder if there is a way to make this DRY-er.

```
s = self.start
e = self.end
if s.x > e.x:
    s.x, e.x = e.x, s.x
if s.y > e.y:
    s.y, e.y = e.y, s.y
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: What is repeating there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basicaly want to sort your data, you may be interested in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted) then:

```
start = self.start
end = self.end
start.x, end.x = sorted((start.x, end.x))
start.y, end.y = sorted((start.y, end.y))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in functions, handling any potential number of attributes to swap:

```
start = self.start
end = self.end

attrs = ["x", "y"]
for attr in attrs:
    start_attr_value, end_attr_value = getattr(start, attr), getattr(end, attr)
    if start_attr_value > end_attr_value:
        setattr(start, attr, end_attr_value)
        setattr(end, attr, start_attr_value)
```

Also note the more explicit `start` and `end` variable names in place of `s` and `e`. I've abbreviated `attribute` as `attr`, but you may go for the full word if you prefer.

---

You may then [extract this into a separate method/function](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) for reusability and readability:

```
def swap_attributes(start, begin, attrs):
    """Meaningful docstring here."""
    for attr in attrs:
        start_attr_value, end_attr_value = getattr(start, attr), getattr(end, attr)
        if start_attr_value > end_attr_value:
            setattr(start, attr, end_attr_value)
            setattr(end, attr, start_attr_value)
```

Usage:

```
swap_attributes(self.start, self.begin, attrs=["x", "y"])
```

Or may be `merge_ranges` would be a better name for the function (depending on the actual problem you are solving with it).

Comment: The code is about the same size for both my way of doing and yours -- what do you think is the best way to do it? EDIT: Mine is smaller by 2 lines, actually.

Comment: @BleedingCatz it is important to understand that unless we are doing the "code golf" here, instead of trying to make the code shorter sacrificing other things, we should strive for better readability, reusability, modularity, follow principles like "DRY" (thumbs up for the question!), follow the "Zen of Python" and the "PEP8" standards making the code Pythonic.

Comment: @BleedingCatz let's though wait for other ideas, may be there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot more code than the original, though.